# Jquery Ajax: Only Page_Load method is being executed, not the intended one

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I'm supposed to return a csv file, so I added this method that I will be calling from the client side. For now, this method is returning a simple string.

```
public partial class ResourceEdit_PriceSheet : xCI.Site.Web.BasePage
{
    protected void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
    }


    [WebMethod]
    public string GenerateVendorPriceSheet(int suppID)
    {
        return "Succes!!!";
    }

}
```

And this is the ajax

```
function exportVendorPriceSheet() {
 var suppID = getParameterByName('SuppID');
 var url = '/ResourceEdit/ResourceEdit_PriceSheet.aspx/GenerateVendorPriceSheet';
 var id = { "suppID": suppID };
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: url,
     data: id,
     dataType: "application/json",
     cache: false,
     success: function (result) {
         alert(result)
    }
  });
};
```

When I run the application, nothing is happening. The break point is not being hit `GenerateVendorPriceSheet` while the one next to `Page_Load` is being executed. And the response contains the whole page instead of "Success!!!".

Yet, all the posts I've read says that's how to call a method from a aspx page. Am I missing something?

Thanks for helping.

====================

Here are some of the headers

```
Request URL:http://localhost/ResourceEdit/ResourceEdit_PriceSheet.aspx/GenerateVendorPriceSheet
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source

Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:11
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

Form Data
suppID=2974
```

Comment: Where does the Ajax call js function resides? As part of the same `.aspx` or in a different external .`js` file? Did changing it to `var id JSON.stringify({ "suppID": suppID });` helps?

Comment: in the same aspx file, which is `ResourceEdit_PriceSheet.aspx`. Let's me try.

Comment: Then change the url to `'ResourceEdit_PriceSheet.aspx/GenerateVendorPriceSheet';`

Comment: Can you also check what you get when you do `alert(result.d)` instead of `alert(result)`?

Comment: I would check the actual (`XMLHttpRequest`) request your browser is sending via browser developer tools. This might be obvious - the page is requested but your webmethod isn't invoked (something "wrong" about the request that prevents the method from being invoked). Web/Page methods expect the "right" request...Hth..

Comment: @DennisR when I remove the leading `/`, I'm getting a `404`. otherwise, I'm getting a `500`. That's because, the request keeps executing the Page_Load method with the wrong parameters.

Comment: @EdSF: I've posted the header of the request from the Chrome Dev tools. Maybe there is something that can help.

Comment: Support for WebMethod is no longer maintained. You should consider switching over to [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api), as it's well supported (and simpler!)

Comment: @mason: Thanks for suggestion, but if I could, I'd never gone into much troubles. This part of the code is in a legacy folder that we don't really modify that much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the header inspection (Chrome dev tools):

- you are sending `Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`

So (`contentType`):

```
$.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: url,
         data: id,
         contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
         dataType: 'json'
```

Hth....

Comment: Now it's complaining that there is no such method (error 500). This is the error I'm getting: `Unknown web method GenerateVendorPriceSheet.
Parameter name: methodName`.

Comment: Mark your webmethod as `public static`

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much. What's the meaning of d?

Comment: `.d` - it's a way to protect yourself from possibly executing valid javascript (returned from some webmethod or some other source). [This explains in detail](http://encosia.com/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/#comment-34045) Hth...