# Page_Load not called on POST request

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, post

I made a nice web page with jquery ajax calls, but noticed that Page_Load is not called for a jquery ajax POST request. I need the Page_Load call for access to the name of the logged in user, to store in the database with data received through POST, as the static WebMethod in code-behind has no access to the Page object.

My question: is it normal that Page_Load is not called on a POST request? If so, how to get the Page object for the user name, without using Page_Load?

In [comment on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26221058/jquery-ajax-only-page-load-method-is-being-executed-not-the-intended-one) I read: Support for WebMethod is no longer maintained. You should consider switching over to Web API, as it's well supported (and simpler!)

But googling did not really result in info about Web API, as this is a very general search term. Any info on this?

---

Update:

My problem is solved by using HttpContext in the static WebMethod, as commented below, so I do not need Page_Load.

Comment: Is your username stored in `session` ?

Comment: @Curiousdev No, username is taken from Page.User.Identity.Name. And Session is also not available for the static WebMethod.

Comment: You're using ajax...so, you won't have a Page_Load after `POST` because your page wasn't refreshed. You can refresh your page on ajax post's response but if you're using ajax this doesn't make much sense. You have to create an strategy to access this value after response. But you need first to understand how ajax request works.

Comment: Ohh ohk than you can do something like this when you post request than declare a variable `var usrName = "@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name";` and than pass this `usrName` as parameter  of POST request in this way you can get `usrName` in static WebMethod

Comment: @ElmerDantas I found a way to run Page_Load by issuing a GET request using XMLHttpRequest from the client side, then in Page_Load avoiding a full page load by doing Request.Write/Flush/End. But I also need a POST request... So GET fires Page_Load, and POST does not?

Comment: Have you tried the `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` from the question you've posted?

Comment: @Curiousdev Great comment, this solves my problem, without needing Page_Load! HttpContext is also available in the static WebMethod in code-behind.

Comment: @ElmerDantas Yes, I set that contentType already.

Comment: Ohhh that's great :-) cheers

Comment: @Roland Why don't you post your answer and marked as answered your own answer so it'll be helpful to others as well

Comment: @Curiousdev Actually, it's you who found the answer on how to get the user name with HttpContext. I just added the obvious code-behind analogy. I'd be more than glad to accept YOUR answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do that

1. In your javascript add a variable which set current `username` and pass this as a parameter to `POST` method.

   `var usrName = "@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name";`
2. HttpContext is also available in the static WebMethod in code-behind so you can directly achieve the same thing using this as well

Comment: With this solution the Page_Load does not need to be called, eliminating my 1st question.